# How to insert ARRAY data type using knex and potsgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm encountring this issue and i'm running out of time so please if anyone could help:
I want to insert this data:

```
const data= {
id:user.id,
choice:'SWOT',
label:['Strengths','Weaknesses','Opportunities','Threats'],
results:[45,5,20,30],
description:'My first Strategic Analysis'}
```

into this table:

```
analyses (
id serial primary key,
userID integer not null,
choice varchar(25) not null,
Label text ARRAY,
Results integer ARRAY,  
description varchar(200),
FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users (id)
```

);

Using knex, this should be smth like:

```
db('analyses').insert({
        userid: data.id,
        choice: data.choice,
        Label:  data.labelG,
        Results: data.resultG,
        description: data.description
    })
```

Since this syntax doesn't work for ARRAY types I wonder how to do it ? 
Some suggested to use knex.raw() however I coudn't get the right syntax for that
Any help?

Comment: you are referring `data.labelG` and `data.resultG`, but you are initializing `data.label` and `data.result`

Answer (score 28):

You can directly pass javascript arrays to your `ARRAY`type of columns. Like this:

```
await knex.schema.createTable('foo', t => {
  t.increments('id');
  t.specificType('intarray', 'integer ARRAY');
  t.specificType('stringarray', 'text ARRAY');
});

await knex('foo').insert({ intarray: [4,3,2,1], stringarray: ['foo','bar'] });

const rows = await knex('foo');
console.log(rows);

// should output: 
// [ anonymous { id: 1, intarray: [ 4,3,2,1 ], stringarray: [ 'foo', 'bar' ] } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

For Postgresql's text array you need to store your data like:

```
{'Strengths','Weaknesses','Opportunities','Threats'}
```

For doing that you can create a function to convert it to common use.

```
db('analyses').insert({
    userid: data.id,
    choice: data.choice,
    Label:  '{"' + data.labelG.join('","') + '"}',
    Results: data.resultG,
    description: data.description
})
```

Also you need to convert it when you fetched them too.

Comment: String generated in this answer seems to be like `{"str1","str2"}` instead of `{'str1','str2'}`. However I suppose pg driver accepts that style too, since this worked for the person asking the question.